# KDE widget - problem with icon size and the parent item

Tags: widget, qml, kde-plasma

I would like to modify the KDE widget [User Switcher](https://github.com/KDE/kdeplasma-addons/tree/master/applets/userswitcher/package) to let the user decide the size of the icons to be shown in the [`fullRepresentation`](https://github.com/KDE/kdeplasma-addons/blob/master/applets/userswitcher/package/contents/ui/main.qml#L113) view. The user set a value in a combobox in the settings, and the view should automatically update.

To achieve this, I've added the code `iconSize: getIconSize(combo_currentIndex)` in each [`ListDelegate` instance](https://github.com/KDE/kdeplasma-addons/blob/master/applets/userswitcher/package/contents/ui/main.qml#L154). Here, `getIconSize` is a simple javascript function that returns the specified value from `units.iconSizes`.

Then, I tried two approaches:

**Approach 1**: In [`ListDelegate.qml`](https://github.com/KDE/kdeplasma-addons/blob/master/applets/userswitcher/package/contents/ui/ListDelegate.qml#L41) I have created the `property alias iconSize: icon.Layout.minimumWidth`. **It doesn't work**, the widget load and shout out this error: `ListDelegate.qml:41:30: Invalid alias target location: Layout`.

**Approach 2**: In [`ListDelegate.qml`](https://github.com/KDE/kdeplasma-addons/blob/master/applets/userswitcher/package/contents/ui/ListDelegate.qml#L41) I have created the `property int iconSize: units.iconSize.medium` (I chose medium because that's the default option in the user settings). Then I changed the `Layouts` properties of the `PlasmaCore.IconItem` as follows:

```
Layout.minimumWidth: iconSize
Layout.maximumWidth: iconSize
Layout.minimumHeight: iconSize
Layout.maximumHeight: iconSize
```

At this point, the size of the icons changes accordingly to the user settings. But the `ListDelegate` item height remain fixed (as it were still using `units.iconSize.medium`), therefore the icons overlaps when the user chooses an icon size greater than medium.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[After reading the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html), I have fully understand how ***Layout*** works.

The solution of **Approach 2** is quite simple. I also needed to set the correct values to the Layout properties `minimumHeight`, `maximumHeight` and `preferredHeight` of the parent element (which is the `RowLayout` ***row***):

```
Layout.minimumHeight: units.iconSizes.tiny
Layout.maximumHeight: units.iconSizes.enormous
Layout.preferredHeight: iconSize
```

The code should be self explanatory. In doing so, the parent `RowLayout` element is able to correctly change it's height to accomodate the icon.